# I uninstalled all apps on LG E440 using Es file explorer

Tags: root-access

I uninstalled all apps on on rooted LG E440 using Es file explorer.
then phone can not boot . it restarts within a second .
I need help.
Android 4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have backed up all your contacts and docs. Then follow these steps to hard reset your phone:

Step 1: Press and hold the Camera button + Volume Down Key+ Power button.

Step 2: When the LG Logo appears on the screen, release Power key holding volume down+camera key.

This shall do the job for you.

Comment: What should that achieve? If Gaston really removed all apps (including system apps – which his question suggests), there's nothing a factory-reset or alike could "restore".

Comment: Oh.. Regrets, i missed that, if Gaston has uninstalled a system app, then factory reset will surely not help him. He shall need to find a stock rom and reflash his phone.

Comment: Yupp. That's what I suggested with my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The mean answer: restore your backup.

Expecting the answer already (you have no backup): Flash the firmware (i.e. re-install the ROM) – see [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575). Nothing else you can do. Just next time, please only do things you understand and know the expected result of ;)

Comment: True my phone can't boot.
what is the name of ROM I can use on LG L4 II phone?

Comment: I don't know which ROM you could take. Please follow the link in my answer, that should get you started.